# Selenium Unable to locate element within an iframe for dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Am incredibly new to Selenium. I'm trying to use it to 'fill out' a web form so that ultimately I can get the results as a dictionary in Python. So far I have

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://my.crawley.gov.uk/en/service/check_my_bin_collection?accept=yes&consentMessageIds[]=24")
sleep(5)
assert "Check bin collections" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('PostcodeSearch')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("RH10 7AB")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

but I'm struggling to get the element on the page no matter what method I choose

Comment: Click, than clear, than click, and wait for a second than send keys... Try

Comment: @HietshKumar I don't even get that far. Code fails on line 8 when trying to find the element

Comment: I am on your page what you want to do , I can see 2 address there

Comment: The human equivalent would be enter a postcode “RH10 7AB”, select house number “12”, click next and then take the information displayed on screen and make a dictionary in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *postcode* field is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://my.crawley.gov.uk/en/service/check_my_bin_collection?accept=yes&consentMessageIds[]=24')
  elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Check bin collections']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#PostcodeSearch")))
  elem.send_keys("RH10 7AB")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://my.crawley.gov.uk/en/service/check_my_bin_collection?accept=yes&consentMessageIds[]=24")
  elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Check bin collections']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PostcodeSearch']")))
  elem.send_keys("RH10 7AB")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: crawley]

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Thanks! I'm now able to get to the page with the results but I think there's another iframe in there I'm not spotting?

Answer (score 1):

Try below lines

```
driver.get("https://my.crawley.gov.uk/en/service/check_my_bin_collection?accept=yes&consentMessageIds[]=24")

# your frame is getting changed you need to switch the frame and wait for it

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('fillform-frame-1'))

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="PostcodeSearch"]')))
time.sleep(1)
# assert "Check bin collections" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('PostcodeSearch')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("RH10 7AB")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now at the page with the hits but I think there's another iframe somewhere? I have `collection_dict = {}

collectiondetails = {"nextrubbish" : (driver.find_element_by_name("rubbishDateNext").text)}
                                      
print(collectiondetails["nextrubbish"])` and it returns nothing but I was hoping it would return Friday 26 June ?